# how do I stop gdmdisplay

Tags: gnome, gdm

I am getting about 65000 log entries per hour from gdm. it generates the standard message: WARNING: GdmDisplay: display lasted 0.050808 seconds
We do not use gnome on this machine and I want to get rid of the noise.  I stopped the gdm3 service, which reduced the number of message from 200K to 65K per hour.